How do I build only the perf script command from the Linux Perf profiler?
I am creating an app in C++ which involves converting the perf.data binary file into text format. This is usually done by using the perf script command in the terminal. However, I want to call the corresponding C function from my code directly, so that the code is platform independent. Theoretically it should be possible because I am not using the profiler, just the binary to text function.
TLDR; Basically I just want 1 small part of the Perf profiler, the binary to text converter, and I want to make it platform independent.
So far, I have dived into the source code of the Linux Perf compiler, and found the main script responsible for the conversion. I have also managed to figure out the entry point C function (cmd_script) and what input parameters it requires. However, I am stumped at how to resolve the dependencies. E.g., some dependencies like the <sys/...> libraries are not part of the Linux kernel, and I am not quite sure if I need them at all.
Can anyone suggest a way to do this?

So you're basically wanting to turn that part of perf into a library function.  Probably some of the sys/ headers are standard POSIX stuff for file I/O that you could replace later, after you've carved out the parts you need from the perf source.  You should end up with one or a few .c files, which include a couple functions you actually want to call, and the rest being code they call.  Once that works, then start worrying about making that perf code portable to non-Linux or even non-POSIX systems like Windows, if you want to eventually do that.

Yes, that's what I am aiming to do. Another problem is the nested dependencies, which I am not quite sure how to resolve
